# How can we get the probability of the complement of $C$ that $P(C^{c})\geq 1-2c-1/n?$

Tags: calculus, probability

> Assume events $A, B, C$. If we have the probability of $P(A)\geq 1-c$, $P(B)\geq 1-c$, and 
>   $$P(A\cap B\cap C)\leq 1/n$$
>
> How can we get the probability of the complement of $C$ that $P(C^{c})\geq 1-2c-1/n?$

We know that $P(A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c)\geq 1- 1/n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(C)\leq P(A\cap B  \cap C)+P(A^{c})+P(B^{c})$ because $  C \subseteq (A\cap B \cap C) \cup B^{c} \cup A^{c}$. Now note that $P(A^{c})<c$ and $P(B^{c})<c$. Hence $P(C) \leq \frac 1 n +c+c$. Finally this gives $P(C^{c})=1-P(C) \geq 1-\frac 1 n -2c$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$C =  [(A \cap B) \cap C] \cup [(A \cap B)^c \cap C]
\subseteq [A \cap B \cap C] \cup A^c \cup B^c$$